# Firebase Javascript saving new info child key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with firebase for a while now and for the past few days can not figure out how to get child key.

This is how database looks like: [image: firebase]

Table in real: [image]

Now here I would need to connect "Vrijeme" with aRacuni.DatumVrijeme and then find out information about what is that specific bill (on my language bill = racun) that I'm looking to change. Then I would like to change "Storno" from 0 to 1, as that specific bill is now cancelled, and to make it secure that it wont get cancelled once again, If storno=1, then you can't cancel it again.

For example:
Bill -MQDTH18PvsnSncjBUzQ
Storno: 0

If I click on that bill in my table, I would like to change Storno to 1.

```
function PopuniTablicuRacuni() {
    var table;
    aRacuni.forEach(function (oRacuni) {
        var VrstaGor = "";

        if (oRacuni.VrstaGoriva == 1) {
            VrstaGor = "Diesel";
        } else if (oRacuni.VrstaGoriva == 2) {
            VrstaGor = "Benzin";
        }
        if (oRacuni.Storno == 1) {
            $("#table_body_storno").append("<tr><td>" + oRacuni.Kolicina + "</td><td>" + VrstaGor + "</td><td>" + oRacuni.DatumVrijeme + "</td><td>" + oRacuni.Zaposlenik + "</td><td>" + oRacuni.Cijena + "</td></tr>");
        } else {
            $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + oRacuni.Kolicina + "</td><td>" + VrstaGor + "</td><td>" + oRacuni.DatumVrijeme + "</td><td>" + oRacuni.Zaposlenik + "</td><td>" + oRacuni.Cijena + "</td></tr>");
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            table = $('#TablicaRacuni').DataTable();

        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#TablicaRacuni tbody#table_body').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            data = table.row(this).data();
            $('#Storno').modal("show");
        });

        $('#TablicaRacuni tbody#table_body_storno').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            alert("Ovaj račun je već storniran.")
        });
    });

}

function Storno() {
    const fb = firebase.database().ref()
    var VrstaGoriva = data[1];
    var KolicinaGoriva = data[0];
    var Vrijeme = data[2];

/*
    now here I would need to connect "Vrijeme" with aRacuni.DatumVrijeme
*/

    if (VrstaGoriva == 'Diesel') {
        aSpremnik_diesel.forEach(function (oSpremnikdiesel) {
            var Stanje = +oSpremnikdiesel.Stanje + +KolicinaGoriva;
            if (Stanje > 20000) {
                window.alert("Maksimalna količina u spremniku je 20000L, nemoguće stornirati.")
            } else {
                data = {
                    Stanje
                }
                fb.child("Spremnik/0").update(data)
                window.location.reload()
            }
        });
    } else if (VrstaGoriva == 'Benzin') {
        aSpremnik_benzin.forEach(function (oSpremnikbenzin) {
            var Stanje = +oSpremnikbenzin.Stanje + +KolicinaGoriva;
            if (Stanje > 20000) {
                window.alert("Maksimalna količina u spremniku je 20000L, nemoguće stornirati.")
            } else {
                data = {
                    Stanje
                }
            }
            fb.child("Spremnik/1").update(data)
            window.location.reload()
        });
    }
}
```

aRacuni:

```
var aRacuni = [];
var oDb = firebase.database();
var oDbRacuni = oDb.ref('Racun');
oDbRacuni.on('value', function (oOdgovorPosluzitelja) {
    aRacuni = [];
    oOdgovorPosluzitelja.forEach(function (oRacuniSnapshot) {
        var oRacuni = oRacuniSnapshot.val();
        aRacuni.push({
            DatumVrijeme: oRacuni.Datumvrijeme,
            Zaposlenik: oRacuni.Zaposlenik_izdao,
            Kolicina: oRacuni.Kolicina,
            VrstaGoriva: oRacuni.Id_goriva,
            Cijena: oRacuni.Cijena,
            Storno: oRacuni.Storno
        });
    });
    PopuniTablicuRacuni();
});
```

JSON:

```
{
  "Racun" : {
    "-M0JqwCxHWpPf4eji_Py" : {
      "Cijena" : "482.90",
      "Datumvrijeme" : "14/12/2020 21:34:14",
      "Id_goriva" : 1,
      "Kolicina" : "55",
      "Storno" : 1,
      "Zaposlenik_izdao" : "name1"
    },
    "-MQDTH18PvsnSncjBUzQ" : {
      "Cijena" : "19509.16",
      "Datumvrijeme" : "4/1/2021 18:36:53",
      "Id_goriva" : 1,
      "Kolicina" : "2222",
      "Storno" : 0,
      "Zaposlenik_izdao" : "name1"
    },
    "-MQDUUzGgakEoAgq_wYE" : {
      "Cijena" : "500.00",
      "Datumvrijeme" : "4/1/2021 18:42:12",
      "Id_goriva" : 1,
      "Kolicina" : "100",
      "Storno" : 0,
      "Zaposlenik_izdao" : "name1"
    },
    "-MQkyAOtOvAoy7-p4Nq0" : {
      "Cijena" : "502.15",
      "Datumvrijeme" : "11/1/2021 11:23:19",
      "Id_goriva" : 2,
      "Kolicina" : "55",
      "Storno" : 0,
      "Zaposlenik_izdao" : "name1"
    },
    "-MQl2uB7RF2FvOyMwePi" : {
      "Cijena" : "180.00",
      "Datumvrijeme" : "11/1/2021 11:48:22",
      "Id_goriva" : 1,
      "Kolicina" : "20",
      "Storno" : 1,
      "Zaposlenik_izdao" : "name1"
    }
  },
  "Spremnik" : [ {
    "Cijena" : 9,
    "Id_spremnika" : 1,
    "Naziv" : "Diesel",
    "Stanje" : 19983
  }, {
    "Cijena" : 9.13,
    "Id_spremnika" : 2,
    "Naziv" : "Benzin",
    "Stanje" : 11550
  } ],
  "Zaposlenik" : [ {
    "Id_zaposlenika" : "EHikAPKrt7ZIiVQvUC5DnZ8yS9y2",
    "Ime_prezime" : "name1"
  }, {
    "Id_zaposlenika" : "Gle0HloemYRhgS30yFYPSiZTftJ3",
    "Ime_prezime" : "name2"
  }, {
    "Id_zaposlenika" : "QtHwSNors3R6AS64z8Z3ArXZCIu2",
    "Ime_prezime" : "name3"
  }, {
    "Id_zaposlenika" : "nZTz6QRrIBfNfDILqimQhr8wAXy2",
    "Ime_prezime" : "name4"
  }, {
    "Id_zaposlenika" : "ZIlEXQyiJOYcq4QjjHkD1Y09OdA2",
    "Ime_prezime" : "name5"
  } ]
}
```

I've made it :)

```
fb.child('Racun').orderByChild('Datumvrijeme').equalTo(Vrijeme).on("value", function (snapshot) {
                console.log(snapshot.val());
                snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
                    _key = data.key;
                    childData = data.val();
                    var Storno = childData.Storno = 1
                    data2 = {
                        Storno
                    }
                    fb.child('Racun/' + _key).update(data2)
                });
            });
```

Comment: Please either use the image hosting provided by Stack Overflow to show your image, or upload the JSON as text instead of a screenshot. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Also note that we have no way of knowing what `aRacuni` is in your code.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, I've updated my question with image and aRacuni

Comment: In the future please add the JSON as text in the way I described. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: That second code snippet at first glance looks fine to me. What doesn't work about it? So: if you step through the code in a debugger, which line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: "fb.child("Racun/").update(data2)" -> throws multiple errors related to child
Basically what It's supposed to  do: after certain bill is cancelled, he should write that in table, to know for future reference that that bill is already cancelled and switch "Storno" from 0 to 1

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about your HTML or application logic. That's why I asked for what specific line is not working as you expect it. Did you step through the code in a debugger yet? If not, do so now. Set a breakpoint on `aRacuni = [];` and run the code in a debugger. Does it reach the breakpoint? If so, step through the code from there and carefully check if each line does what you expect it to do. If not, which line is not working as you expect?

Comment: I have found with debugger that I wrote code completely wrong, as aRacuni.forEach gives me first in order (-M0JqwCxHWpPf4eji_Py) and not exact one that I clicked on.
I have another idea, I have edited my first post.